# How to lint .cshtml files?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, eslint, lint

Using ESLint, it's easy to lint *.js files. Using a plugin like html or script-tag, it's also simple to lint JavaScript code inside  tags in *.html files.

However, when it comes to script tags inside *.cshtml files, I'm stuck.

Does anyone know how to lint *.cshtml files or recommend a different linting tool for that?

Comment: In [eslint-plugin-html](https://github.com/BenoitZugmeyer/eslint-plugin-html) there's a configurable list of [html extensions](https://github.com/BenoitZugmeyer/eslint-plugin-html#htmlhtml-extensions). Have you tried adding `.cshtml` to that?